# How do I change only the angle of a certain PNG relative to the position of the mouse? (Python, Pygame)

Tags: python, pygame, mouse, shooter

Basically, I'm doing a game for a school project and I am not really sure how to make a player point towards the mouse pointer in a pygame tab. also if anyone has ideas of how i could point a bullet towards the mouse and then fire in the direction of the mouse after i click fire (without continuously changing angles towards the mouse pointer) that would be awesome

Here is my code:

```
import pygame
import os


WIDTH, HEIGHT = 900, 500
WIN = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption('First Person Shooter')

WHITE = (255,255,255)

FPS = 60
VEL = 5
BULLET_VEL = 7

CHARACTER_PLAYER_ONE = pygame.image.load(os.path.join('Python', 'player_one.png'))
CHARACTER_PLAYER_ONE = pygame.transform.rotate(pygame.transform.scale(CHARACTER_PLAYER_ONE, (55, 40)), 90)

def draw_window(one):
    WIN.fill(WHITE)
    WIN.blit(CHARACTER_PLAYER_ONE, (one.x, one.y))
    pygame.display.update() 


def one_handle_movement(keys_pressed, one):
        if keys_pressed[pygame.K_a] and one.x - VEL > -15: # left
            one.x -= VEL
        if keys_pressed[pygame.K_d] and one.x + VEL + one.width < 925: # right
            one.x += VEL
        if keys_pressed[pygame.K_w] and one.y - VEL > -15: # up
            one.y -= VEL
        if keys_pressed[pygame.K_s] and one.y + VEL + one.height < 500: # down
            one.y += VEL


def main():
    one = pygame.Rect(100, 300, 55, 40)

    bullets = []

    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    run = True
    while run:
        clock.tick(FPS)
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False

            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                    bullet = pygame.Rect()
        


        keys_pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        one_handle_movement(keys_pressed, one)
        draw_window(one)

    pygame.quit()


if __name__ == '__main__':                
    main()
```

I would really appreciate help if you are willing to provide it!

P.S. i didn't really define the bullets yet, but the player one sprite is the main thing im looking for at the moment

Much of this code is as shown in *https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jO6qQDNa2UY*

-Luckee365-

Comment: first you have to get position of `mouse` and `gun`, and calculate distance (`dx, dy`) between `mouse` and `gun` and value `dy/dy` gives you `tangle of angle` - and this `angle` you can use to rotate `bullet`. SO it needs some `math` ;) Luckly `PyGame.math.Vector` should have functions to calculate `distance` and/or `angle` between two points.

Comment: BTW: because `one` is a `Rect()` so instead of `one.x + one.width`. You can use `one.right`. You have also `one.left`, `one.top`, `one.botton`. `one.center`, `one.centerx`, `one,centery`, `one.topleft`, `one.size`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

**Math:** `tan(angle) = dy/dx` so `angle = arctangle(dy/dx)`

And as `dx, dy` you can use differnce between mouse position and gun/player position.

---

Get positions for mouse and gun/player.

```
mouse_x,  mouse_y  = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
player_x, player_y = player_rect.center
```

Calculate distance (dx, dy) between mouse and gun/player

```
dx = mouse_x - player_x
dy = mouse_y - player_y
```

Now `dy/dx` should give `tangle or angle` so I can use `arctangle` to get `angle` (in `radians`).

```
angle_radians = math.atan2(dy, dx)

angle = math.degrees(angle_radians)
```

And now rotate image with `-angle` (to rotate in correct direction).

```
player_image = pygame.transform.rotate(original_player_image, angle).convert_alpha()
```

To get better quality of rotated image you should always use original image.

You also have to use `convert_alpha()` to get colors in `RGBA` with transparent background.

And new `Image` needs new `Rect` with position from previous `Rect`.

```
player_rect = player_image.get_rect(centerx=player_x, centery=player_y)
```

---

Full working code. It rotates player to mouse position (even when it moves).

I used `set_caption` to display positions and angle in window's title.

```
import pygame
import os
import math

# --- constants ---  # PEP8: `UPPER_CASE_NAMES` for constants

WIDTH, HEIGHT = 900, 500

WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
RED   = (255, 0, 0)

FPS = 60
VEL = 5
BULLET_VEL = 7

# --- main ---  # PEP8: `lower_case_names` for variables

pygame.init()

WIN = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption('First Person Shooter')

#CHARACTER_PLAYER_ONE = pygame.image.load(os.path.join('Python', 'player_one.png'))
original_player_image = pygame.surface.Surface((100, 100)).convert_alpha()
original_player_image.fill((255,0,0,255))
original_player_image = pygame.transform.rotate(pygame.transform.scale(original_player_image, (55, 40)), 90)


player_image = original_player_image.copy()
player_rect  = player_image.get_rect(centerx=100, centery=300)

def draw_window():
    WIN.fill(WHITE)
    WIN.blit(player_image, player_rect)
    pygame.display.update() 

def one_handle_movement(keys_pressed, one):
        if keys_pressed[pygame.K_a] and one.left   - VEL > -15: # left
            one.x -= VEL
        if keys_pressed[pygame.K_d] and one.right  + VEL < 925: # right
            one.x += VEL
        if keys_pressed[pygame.K_w] and one.top    - VEL > -15: # up
            one.y -= VEL
        if keys_pressed[pygame.K_s] and one.bottom + VEL < 500: # down
            one.y += VEL


def main():
    global player_image
    global player_rect
    
    bullets = []

    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    run = True
    while run:
        
        clock.tick(FPS)
        
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False

            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                    bullet = pygame.Rect()
        
        # get positions 
        
        mouse_x,  mouse_y  = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        player_x, player_y = player_rect.center

        # get angle
        dx = mouse_x - player_x
        dy = mouse_y - player_y
        
        angle = math.degrees(math.atan2(dy, dx))
        
        pygame.display.set_caption(f"player: {player_x}, {player_y} | mouse: {mouse_x}, {mouse_y} | angle: {angle}")
        
        # rotate
        
        player_image = pygame.transform.rotate(original_player_image, -angle).convert_alpha()
        
        # assign original center to new rectagle
        
        player_rect = player_image.get_rect(centerx=player_x, centery=player_y)

        # ---
        
        keys_pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        one_handle_movement(keys_pressed, player_rect)
        
        draw_window()

       
    pygame.quit()


if __name__ == '__main__':                
    main()
```

---

**EDIT:**

Pygame has [pygame.math.Vector2.angle_to()](https://web.archive.org/web/20211006193710/http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/math.html#pygame.math.Vector2.angle_to) to calculate angle (in degrees) between two verctors (points) but for some reason I got wrong results and couldn't find mistake.

```
mouse  = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
player = player_rect.center

angle = pygame.math.Vector2(player).angle_to(mouse)
```

BTW: today pygame doc is not accessible so I used link to its copy on archive.org.

---

**EDIT:**

This gives correct `angle`

```
mouse  = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
player = player_rect.center

dist  = pygame.math.Vector2(mouse) - pygame.math.Vector2(player)

angle = pygame.math.Vector2().angle_to(dist)
```

---

````
def main():
    global player_image
    global player_rect
    
    bullets = []

    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    run = True
    while run:
        
        clock.tick(FPS)
        
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False

            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                    bullet = pygame.Rect()
        
        # get positions 
        
        mouse  = mouse_x,  mouse_y  = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        player = player_x, player_y = player_rect.center

        # get angle

        wrong_angle = pygame.math.Vector2(mouse).angle_to(player)   # gives results different then I expect

        dist  = pygame.math.Vector2(mouse) - pygame.math.Vector2(player)
        angle = pygame.math.Vector2().angle_to(dist)   # gives results different then I expect
        
        pygame.display.set_caption(f"player: {player_x}, {player_y} | mouse: {mouse_x}, {mouse_y} | angle: {angle} | wrong: {wrong_angle}")
        
        # rotate
        
        player_image = pygame.transform.rotate(original_player_image, -angle).convert_alpha()
        
        # assign original center to new rectagle
        
        player_rect = player_image.get_rect(centerx=player_x, centery=player_y)

        # ---
        
        keys_pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        one_handle_movement(keys_pressed, player_rect)
        
        draw_window()

       
    pygame.quit()
```
````